# Android - reopen main activity from notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

Launcher activity for my app is called **LaunchActivity**. Inside this activity I check if the user is logged. If yes, then a network call is made to validate the user and if everything is fine **MainActivity** is started. If user runs app for first time or user validation fails, **LoginActivity** runs.

Inside LaunchActivity there is function that runs appropriate activity:

```
private void start(Class<? extends Activity> startActivity) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, startActivity);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

App is receiving notifications. After notification click i want to open app or bring it top if it is on background.

Code responsible for notification intent:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, LaunchActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("SHOW_NOTIFICATION_LIST", "");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            intent,
            0);
    builder.setContentIntent(notificationIntent);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
```

The problem is that with my current implementation after click, LaunchActivity is reopened even when MainActivity is on background. I can not figure out how to make the pending intent reopen just **MainActivity** (without LaunchActivity and valdation) if it is on background OR start **LaunchActivity** when there are no activity running on background ( app is not running ). I would be very grateful for any kind of help.

edit:

Activities declaration inside manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".activities.LaunchActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="userPortrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please post your Manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the absurd behavior is that because you are finishing the `LaunchActivity` when you call `start()`

```
private void start(Class<? extends Activity> startActivity) {

   ....
    finish(); // This is the culprit
  ....
}
```

Remove `finish()` from `start()` and it will work fine as expected.

If you can't remove `finish()` because of your app behavior, then change your `PendingIntent` to launch `MainActivity` instead of `LaunchActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
```

And in `MainActivity's onCreate()` check if the user is already logged in . If not then navigate him to your `LoginActivity`.

Comment: i dont think this is the problem - before i start MainActivity i need to finish launch activity because is is no longer needed - it is just intermediate activity

Comment: i just removed finish() and it works good. but could you explain why this actually works that way ? Without finish(), LaunchActivity is still alive so why after pending intent fires, MainActivity is brought back to top instead of LaunchActivity ?? ( in my case LaunchActivity also has app splash view )

Comment: This is because of intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER). This behaves the same way as you are relaunching your app from the recent apps stack.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BroadcastReceiver which reacts to three different intents

- `ACTION_CREATED`: set flag to true
- `ACTION_DESTROYED`: set flag to false
- `ACTION_LAUNCH`: if flag, start `MainActivity`, otherwise start `LaunchActivity`

(flag can be e.g. a boolean in sharedpreferences or a static field)

in `MainActivity`:

- in `onCreate`: send `ACTION_CREATED` broadcast
- in `onDestroy`: send `ACTION_DESTROYED`broadcast

The notification should send an `ACTION_LAUNCH`broadcast.

Note: actions can be named as whatever you want. They also should start with you package name, so you don't interfere with other apps.

Comment: sounds good - with this i simply control the lifecycle on the MainActivity but will i be abble to send broadcast intent when user clicks the notification ?

Comment: just use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` instead of `PendingIntent.getActivity`